# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/AllPost.vue' in '/var/www/html/proj/resources/js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

Laravel 8.21
Updated all node_modules using npm
When I do npm run watch

```
I get below error:
user@user-HVM-domU:/var/www/html/proj$ sudo npm run watch

> watch
> mix watch

glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}
ERROR in ./resources/js/routes.js 1:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/AllPost.vue' in '/var/www/html/ginvoice/resources/js'

ERROR in ./resources/js/routes.js 2:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/AddPost.vue' in '/var/www/html/ginvoice/resources/js'

ERROR in ./resources/js/routes.js 3:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/EditPost.vue' in '/var/www/html/ginvoice/resources/js'

ERROR in /js/app
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/var/www/html/ginvoice/resources/sass/app.scss' in '/var/www/html/ginvoice'

webpack compiled with 4 errors
```

- My sudo nano resources/js/routes.js

  import AllPosts from './components/AllPost.vue';
  import AddPost from './components/AddPost.vue';
  import EditPost from './components/EditPost.vue';

  export const routes = [
  {
  name: 'home',
  path: '/',
  component: AllPosts
  },
  {
  name: 'add',
  path: '/add',
  component: AddPost
  },
  {
  name: 'edit',
  path: '/edit/:id',
  component: EditPost
  }
  ];

1. sudo nano package.json

> ```
> {
>     "private": true,
>     "scripts": {
>         "dev": "npm run development",
>         "development": "mix",
>         "watch": "mix watch",
>         "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
>         "hot": "mix watch --hot",
>         "prod": "npm run production",
>         "production": "mix --production"
>     },
>     "devDependencies": {
>         "axios": "^0.21",
>         "laravel-mix": "^6.0.9",
>         "lodash": "^4.17.19",
>         "postcss": "^8.1.14",
>         "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
>         "sass": "^1.32.2",
>         "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
>         "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
>         "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
>     },
>     "dependencies": {
>         "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
>         "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
>         "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.2",
>         "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
>         "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
>         "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
>         "jquery": "^3.5.1",
>         "moment": "^2.29.1",
>         "npm-check-updates": "^10.2.5",
>         "pdfmake": "^0.1.69",
>         "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
>         "vue": "^2.6.12",
>         "vue-axios": "^3.2.2",
>         "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
>         "vue-router": "^3.4.9"
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Are the files on disk and cased correctly? Can you see them with `ls`? As a sidenote, it's considered best practice to not serve web apps using `sudo` with npm. If your user doesn't have the permissions it needs to write to that directory, you could move your app to a different directory and point your Apache or Nginx or whatever config to that location if need be.

Comment: yes all case for file names reflect ls. To make dev faster I use sudo. This issue pops up when I update laravel-mix to latest along with Laravel 8.21 .. Laravel 8.21 with exactly same setup works with older version of laravel-mix. Any idea? Anyone tried with latest see this issue?